# URL is not pointing to https on iframe

Tags: https, ubuntu-14.04

In our site we are loading a calnedar api function that works on http (cdn.instantcal.com) . While loading this site on our wordpress site with https its not working and getting an error:

> "Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.geo.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=362&action=edit' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://cdn.instantcal.com/cvj.html'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS."

In order to fix the Mixed Iframe Issue in our Nginx Proxy server we configured a new site on https calendar.geopc.com and that proxies to cdn.instantcal.com.

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name calendar.geopc.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://cdn.instantcal.com;
                        proxy_set_header Host      cdn.instantcal.com;
                       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        }
```

Then In Iframe we given the url as

```
<iframe id="cv_if5"
 src="https://calendar.geopc.com/cvir.html?id=citus.com%2F60dcfe0d8c42638%2Fcalendar.ics&amp;theme=RE&amp;ccolor=%23ffffc0&amp;dims=1&amp;gtype=cv_daygrid&amp;gcloseable=0&amp;gnavigable=1&amp;gperiod=day7&amp;itype=cv_simpleevent"
 width="780" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

But in Iframe we are getting the same error

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.geo.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=362&action=edit' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://calendar.geopc.com/cvj.html?idcloseable=0&gnavigable=1&gperiod=da'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

When we directly access the url calendar.geopc.com on https its working fine on https. But please let me know whats the issue? Is it on Iframe or on Nginx. Can anyone please help us?

Comment: The webpage you include use http resources. It's blocked for security reason because the iframe is https. (And you can't have an http iframe in an https webpage). Just ask geo.com to fix their code.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem was that the **iframe** source URL was an HTTP URL, which browsers block when requested from an HTTPS page. With your `proxy_pass` setup, the **iframe** source URL is an HTTPS URL, which removes one part of the problem.

However, the code loaded from the calendar service via your proxy is requesting more resources, and they have direct URLs to their original service, which are requested over HTTP.

You need to get a calendar service that supports HTTPS or implement your own, there is no other way to fix this problem.